# Java getResourceAsStream is always null in JAR

Tags: java, spring, jar

I know, they're a lot of articles discuss it...but It did not work for me.
I have html file like below structure

```
src/main/resources
---------abc.html
```

[image]

I use Input stream to read it

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.html");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
                    content = reader.lines()
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

and build the jar file with maven:

```
mvn clean package
```

and run the project to jar file and run with cmd:

```
java -jar myproject.jar
```

But I always receive the java.lang.NullPointerException. Pls advice

Comment: Do you have `src/main/abc.html` or `src/main/resources/abc.html`? The directory name is usually `resources` not `resource`.

Comment: What if you omit the `/`?

Comment: Did you try ```InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.html");``` ?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki: it's src/main/resource/abc.html

Comment: hi khelwood: it's the same.

Comment: How are you building the JAR? Do you use a build too like Maven?

Comment: @djharten, yes. I did it

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, yes, I use mvn clean package

Comment: getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("main/resource/abc.html") you tried this and maybe even with src as well? open extract your jar like a zip file and check its structure.

Comment: What does `zipinfo -1 myproject.jar | grep abc` print?

Comment: Check inside the jar (for instance with 7zip). By the way: `new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or such.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, I can see the html in myproject.zip\WEB-INF\classes

Comment: @JoopEggen, it's still not work :(

Comment: You are packaging a WAR not a JAR if you have `WEB-INF`. Do you know what exactly are you packaging e.g. Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, yes..it's spring boot...correct path is \BOOT-INF\classes\, I can see the html file

Comment: Case-sensitive names, and not coincidentally with Windows hiding the file extension: there actually be a `abc,html.html` (contradicted by your screenshot). Also better use `Xyz.class.getResurceAsStream` i.o. `getClass()`..

Comment: @JoopEggen, It is just html file: abc.html

Comment: If you saw the file inside the jar /abc,html then getResource really cannot return null.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) when using Maven the resource directory should be `src/main/resources` unless you modify the default layout.

Rename `resource` to `resources` and verify that the JAR file contains the HTML file:

```
zipinfo -1 myproject.jar | grep abc
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake..it should be resources...I updated the question